# Passing String array Values from Java native interface to Delphi wrapper class

Tags: delphi, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass the String array values from Java native interface to Delphi wrapper class. 
But didn't getting any array values from JNI.  How can declare Array String in Delphi Wrapper class.
How to convert JNI String array.

This is my Delphi wrapper class Code:

```
function Java_com_erm_controller_ARMReports_A3(PEnv: PJNIEnv; Obj: JObject;
  ex_BSName_ALM: JStrings): Integer; stdcall; export;
var
  objRpt: TARMReports;
begin
  Result := objRpt.A3(aBSName_ALM);
  JVM.Free;
  objRpt.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This question doesn't look complete - eg the paragraph "enter code here". Please enter the code :) Also I think you need to add more details about what you're doing and the Java library you're working with. Also, is your problem converting Java strings to Delphi strings, or is it that the library isn't returning any strings into aBSName_ALM?

Comment: `JStrings` is not defined in Delphi's JNI units, so what is `JStrings` actually declared as in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what `JStrings` is actually declared as (it is not defined in Delphi's JNI wrapper units), I can only guess that you need to do something like this:

```
function Java_com_erm_controller_ARMReports_A3(PEnv: PJNIEnv; Obj: JObject;
  ex_BSName_ALM: JStrings): Integer; stdcall; export;
var
  strs: array of String;
  len, i: Integer;
  el: JNIObject;
  ...
begin
  ...
  len := PEnv.GetArrayLength(PEnv, ex_BSName_ALM);
  SetLength(strs, len);
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
  begin
    el := PEnv.GetObjectArrayElement(PEnv, ex_BSName_ALM, i);
    strs[i] := JStringToString(JString(el));
  end;
  ...
end;
```